# CI job rule to only execute over main when the tag is present

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have following job rule:

```
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "main" && $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v[0-9](?:\.[0-9]){2,3}/'
      when: on_success
```

What I want is to only execute this job when a change to `main` to push (direct or through MR) and has a `tag` matching the pattern.

But I have tried all the ways but this job never executes. This is my flow of commit

```
git tag -a v0.0.2 -m "Adding version"
git push origin dev # and merge to main, or directly
git push origin main
```

my understanding is above is a commit over `main` with the specified tag and should trigger this job but it isn't.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tag has no branch. It's just a pointer to some commit. Why not run it just on tags? I do not think gitlab supports checking if there exists a tag that points to the current HEAD, you would have to script that yourself.

Comment: if only on tags then it will also run on all the branches.. I understand tags are bound to branch.. but I just want to bound job to both.. i.e. if its `main` and has a `tag` .. if it’s a commit on dev branch with tag then don’t run, if it is a commit on main without a tag then also don’t run.

Comment: `I understand tags are bound to branch` no, tags are bound to a commit. It's a pointer. Tag v0.1.1 points to commit abcdef. Branch main points to commit abcdef. It's unrelated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: **It's not possible**. You cannot mate these two conditions at push time because, as stated in the comments, tags have no relation to branches. This is a concept rooted in `git` and not something GitLab has control over.

When you push a tag, there is no reference to any branch. It points to a **commit**. That commit may exist on one branch, many branches, or even no branch at all. When you tag a commit and push the tag, it doesn't matter what your current working branch is. There's no branch information associated with that push of the tag.

That's part of the reason why branch pipelines are separate from tag pipelines and why the `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` variable is not present for tag pipelines and `CI_COMMIT_TAG` is not present on branch pipelines. That's also why the `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` variable is **EITHER** the branch name **OR** the tag.

Therefore, if you're expecting `CI_COMMIT_TAG` to be present, `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` and `CI_COMMIT_TAG` will **always** be the same. Hence, your rule can never evaluate as true as your rule relies on them being different, which, inherently, can never happen based on the properties discussed above.

Illustrated in a table:

| Variable | Branch pipelines | Tag Pipelines |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME | my-branch | tag-name |
| CI_COMMIT_BRANCH | my-branch |  |
| CI_COMMIT_TAG |  | tag-name |

What you're asking for is simply not possible using `rules:`.

You might be able to achieve *something* like what you want by introspecting the HEAD on a branch pipeline job for `main` using `git` to see if a tag matching the pattern exists and then using [dynamic child pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/parent_child_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines) to trigger the desired workflow thereafter.

But that approach is error-prone for a number of reasons and the better route is almost certainly to rethink your workflow.